# Использование jQuery offset

Tags: jquery

Добрый день

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с jQuery offset.

Вот **[что сделал](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/AtHsN/2/)** я.

**Что получилось сделать**:  задать topTitle.

**Что не получилось сделать**:

1. окно предупреждение появляется только у первого элемента, а нужно, чтобы появлялось у всех элементов с class="prompt";
2. выравнивание окна предупреждения относительно центра элемента с class="prompt";
3. разный текст в разных окнах предупреждения.

-

```
<input type="text" class="prompt" />
<textarea class="prompt"></textarea>
<input type="button" class="prompt" value="Отправить" />
​
```

-

```
textarea {
    margin: 75px 0 0 63px;
    display: block;
}

input[type="button"] {
    margin: 90px 0 0 135px;
    display: block;
}

.title {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
}
​
```

-

```
tip();

function tip() {
    var prompt = $('.prompt');
    var offset = prompt.offset();
    var topTitle = prompt.height() + offset.top + 15;
    var leftTitle = offset.left - prompt.width() / 4;
    var titleText = 'Введите данные';

    $('<span class="title"></span>')
        .css({
            'top' : topTitle,
            'left' : leftTitle
        })
        .appendTo('body')
        .text(titleText);
}
​
```

Comment: @Deonis, нет, я имел ввиду разный контент. В общем, глупость спросил (сначала спросил, потом подумал).

Comment: @Alex83, Повторюсь - используйте связку: [Ajax](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81) => PHP => Ajax

Comment: @Deonis, еще один вопрос, необходимо сверху, по центру добавить стрелку(указатель). Я сделал следующее: 

    $('<p class="title"><span></span>' + titleText[i] + '</p>').insertAfter(el);


    // position arrow for prompt
    var titleArrowLeft = ($('.title').width() - $('.title span').width()) / 2 + 30;
    $('.title span').css('left', titleArrowLeft);

Все почти ровно, а хотелось бы идеально. Не подскажите как осуществить?

Comment: @Deonis, подскажите пожалуйста, какую функцию выполняет число 10 в следующей строчке кода?

    var bp = (parseInt($(el).css('border-left-width'),10) + parseInt($(el).css('padding-left'),10))*2;

Comment: @Deonis, подскажите пожалуйста... всю голову уже сломал...

Comment: @Alex83, Это **radix** - основание системы счисления. В нашем случае - десятичная.P.S. Я бы, на вашем месте, психонул и хоть бы глазком посмотрел, что ж такое [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) и его синтаксис ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае, для максимально точного позиционирования подсказок, надо стараться максимально учитывать все погрешности. Многое может зависить от унаследованных значений конкретного элемента. [В этом примере](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/AtHsN/27/), я учел основные неточности, а дальше будете подтачивать под себя сами.

P.S. Комментарии там набросал, но если чего не ясно - спрашивайте.

Comment: @Deonis, спасибо. Проблему позиционирования, я решил немного иначе, а именно: 

    leftTitle = offset.left + (prompt.width() - $('.title').width()) / 2 - 17;

Объясните пожалуйста, каким образом подсказки будут добовляться с сервера, просто я пока далек от этого, но хотелось бы понять общую картину.

Comment: > Объясните пожалуйста, каким образом подсказки будут добовляться с сервера

Это вы меня спрашиваете? )) Много лет назад, меня с позором выгнали из клуба телепатов, т.к. я не проявил способностей в этом направлении )) Ну, разные способы есть, а какой выбрали вы - я не в курсе. Я бы вариант с Ajax-ом попробовал.

Comment: @Deonis, не могу понять как увеличить верхний отступ между элементом и подсказкой... И почему верхние отступы у всех элементов разные?

Comment: Прошу прощения, вопрос снят. Спасибо.

Comment: @Deonis, подскажите, а как быть, если на разных страницах - разный текст подсказок?

Comment: Я же вроде стелал так, что ширина блока высчитывается автоматом. Или что вы имели в виду?